# GDAL - csv to TIFF, struggling with gdal.Rasterize

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, gdal-rasterize

I am looking to interpolate some dataset via IDW with gdal. I am first trying to create a tiff out of my data to then be able to interpolate it.

My code is returning no error however the file created is wrong and does not localise the site properly, I was wondering if anyone could help?

At the moment, I have made vrt from csv but then I am hitting an issue with gdal.Rasterize.

Extract of csv:

```
VWC%,Latitude,Longitude
24.2,50.563717,4.518543
24.5,50.563708,4.518533
28,50.563715,4.518515
25.5,50.563722,4.518498
21.3,50.563728,4.518493
22.2,50.563738,4.518475
27.2,50.563752,4.518463
24.8,50.56375,4.518445
27.5,50.563758,4.518422
25.9,50.563752,4.51842
25.4,50.563763,4.518437
25.3,50.56377,4.518457
26.6,50.563782,4.518455
```

Code:

```
f = open("green9.vrt", "w")
f.write( "<OGRVRTDataSource> \n\
    <OGRVRTLayer name=\"green9\"> \n\
        <SrcDataSource>green9.csv</SrcDataSource> \n\
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType> \n\
        <GeometryField encoding=\"PointFromColumns\" x=\"x\" y=\"y\" z=\"value\"/> \n\
    </OGRVRTLayer> \n\
</OGRVRTDataSource> ")

f.close()

r = gdal.Rasterize("output.tif", "green9.vrt", outputSRS = "EPSG:3857", xRes = 10, yRes = -10, attribute = "value", noData = np.nan)
r = None
```

I have tried as well creating a generic tiff file first but it did not change anything (or I did not manage to do it properly…)

Comment: I believe that yRes should be positive as well.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks, statements of appreciation, etc within your posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I completely avoid to convert raster to use directly vector to generate interpolated raster instead of going through generate raster from points then do raster interpolation from generated raster with the following

```
from osgeo import gdal

with open("green9.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write('''VWC%,Latitude,Longitude
24.2,50.563717,4.518543
24.5,50.563708,4.518533
28,50.563715,4.518515
25.5,50.563722,4.518498
21.3,50.563728,4.518493
22.2,50.563738,4.518475
27.2,50.563752,4.518463
24.8,50.56375,4.518445
27.5,50.563758,4.518422
25.9,50.563752,4.51842
25.4,50.563763,4.518437
25.3,50.56377,4.518457
26.6,50.563782,4.518455''')

with open("green9.vrt", "w") as f:
    f.write('''<OGRVRTDataSource> 
    <OGRVRTLayer name="green9"> 
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">green9.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS> 
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType> 
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude" z="VWC%"/> 
    </OGRVRTLayer> 
</OGRVRTDataSource>''')

nn = gdal.Grid("nearest.tif", "green9.vrt", zfield='VWC%' , algorithm="nearest")
nn = None

nn = gdal.Grid("invdist.tif", "green9.vrt", zfield='VWC%' , algorithm="invdist")
nn = None
```

Most credits to video series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfC3KpL4PRw and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSnJ2VXNV3c

Look also at Python API for `osgeo.gdal.Grid` and `osgeo.gdal.GridOptions` at https://gdal.org/python/ and to https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html#interpolation-algorithms for setting algorithms parameters for interpolating image generation.

Comment: Works perfectly!!! thank you so so so much!! It did the trick and thanks for the videos as well!

Comment: Yes. It was just more simple this way for standalone demo but you can comment all the blocks starting with `with open(...` as long as you have the vrt file and the csv file. Only the `nn = gdal.Grid(...` and later are really useful

Comment: got it! thanks again!